# How do I import an AIDE project into IntelliJ?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, aide-ide

"AIDE" is an IDE for Android. It handles Java, Native Development, HTML dev, etc.

More specifically, I am trying to understand how I import a template LibGDX project started in AIDE, and open the project for running in the normal IntelliJ IDE, not the specific JetBrains Android Emulator version.

I imported the project, but cannot understand how to compile and execute the project, and I suspect I have imported the project incorrectly.

Can anyone help me to understand the process for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IntelliJ 15, you must click "Import Project" on the into screen:

[image]

You then locate the ".project" file under "gdx-game" (or "gdx-game-android", but eventually you need to add both), and select it.

[image]

You will then configure the project settings, such as directory. You select 
"$project_name$" if it is not already checked. You will also click 
"Open Project Structure After Import":

[image]

Enter the name for the main project, and select the main SDK for the project:

[image]

You now navigate to the "Modules" section, and then rename the module ("project") from "$project_name$" to "gdx-game" (if you are in fact currently importing the "gdx-game" project).

You must also select the proper Module SDK to use in compilation of the project.
For "gdx-game", this would be a normal Java SDK such as Java SDK 1.7.
For "gdx-game-android", this would be "Project SDK (Android API 21 Platform)" by default, but if it does not appear you can select "Android 21 Platform(java version "1.7.0_79")":

[image]
[image]

You will now click the addition symbol, also pictured above (circled in red in image 4), in order to import the next module of the project ("gdx-game" or "gdx-game-android").

Again, you will navigate to the appropriate folder and locate the second ".project" file.

Upon import of the module, rename it in the same manner as you did with the first module. Alter it's SDK as well.

This should be all you need for a basic import of a project, but you may need to add libraries and such, depending on your projects needs obviously.